# Facebook OGP meta tags are not working in asp.net MVC

Tags: .net, facebook

I had implemented facebook like button in asp.net MVC using XFBML. I had also added OGP meta tags like og:title, og:Url, og:Image but these tags are not doing any affect on wall post...it showing only url not showing its Title which is given in og:Title meta tag

Comment: You should use the [Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check and debug your page. Also, I hope you did not use caps like you wrote, it's not *og:Url* but *og:url*

Comment: Can you maybe share the url in question so that I, or someone else, can check instead of speculating ?

Comment: Sir :). The like button you are using has a url which people actually "like" when they click the button. You might have more than one url of course, but I want just one example so I can see the source of it and I can tell you why you can only see the title.

Comment: That url returns an empty response, I just see a blank white page, and when I view the source I see a blank white page.

Answer (score 2):

You can't come here and expect people to just do the work for you.

You need to actually try things yourself, to research, to read, to experience things on your own, and then you can come back here with a specific problem you are facing with.

The facebook api has a pretty decent documentation, most of the things are laid out there in a straight forward way.
Have you tried to read what it says about the [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)?

Comment: The link you shared here is a blank page, that's not what I call "implementation". If you have something else, then share it.

Comment: Guide you to what? I don't even understand what you want to do. If you want to control how facebook displays your pages, then read the link I gave you in my answer, to the open graph documentation, it's all in there.

Comment: You can't add meta tags to google.com since you don't own it. The like button works based on a url, then facebook send a request to the url, get the content back and extract the needed info. You can control that info by adding og tags to it, but not if you don't own the page. You are showing lack of basic understanding of the subject, and that you haven't researched it enough. I'm not about to teach you all of that, I'm sorry but what you're asking for is WAY to big.

Comment: But I can't help you like this, since I don't know what's wrong. I sent you to the documentation. Go and read, that's how I learned.

Comment: You won't get a title, when I try that url I get: "This webpage has a redirect loop". Please, don't waste my time. Check things yourself before you post them. How hard can it be to open that url in the browser yourself?!

Comment: Are you serious?? How should I know?! it's not my server, I don't have access to the logs, what do you want from me? I'm not replying to your questions any more, it's pointless.